# How to style my javascript innerHTML into separate components?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm mapping through an array of objects, but it displays everything within one line.

I want to display this as if it's 2 separate cards.

```
      let data = [
        {
          name: 'Person 1',
          age: '30'
        },
        {
          name: 'Person 2',
          age: '30'
        },
      ];

      const info = document.querySelector('#info');

      let details = data.map(function(item) {
        return ' ' + item.name + ' ' + 'is ' + item.age;
      });

      info.innerHTML = details;
```

I only have one `p` tag, so it just displays the name and age all within that one p tag.

```
     <p id="info"></p>
```

So it just looks like this

```
Person 1 is 30, Person 2 is 30.
```

What I'd like it to do is be wrapped in a custom div and essentially be a stand alone card.

So like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is create two separate divs or paragraphs (whatever you need), each holding one persons information. Then you could create an array that holds the objects within. Something like this

```js
let data = [
        {
          name: 'Person 1',
          age: '30'
        },
        {
          name: 'Person 2',
          age: '30'
        },
      ];

      const info = document.querySelector('#info');
       const infoTwo = document.querySelector('#info2');

      

      info.innerHTML = data[0].name + ' ' + 'is ' + data[0].age;
       infoTwo.innerHTML = data[1].name + ' ' + 'is ' + data[1].age;
```

```html
<p id = "info"></p>
<p id = "info2"></p>
```

Comment: it works for this example, but imagine  I have 10 objects, then I'd have to write 10 different <p> tags and add them each to the JS

Comment: I'll think of something hopefully

Answer (score 0):

It'd be more like this. You could just add them to `div`'s... that's very close to how ReactJS does it by using JSX, but by using plain JS, it is:

```js
let data = [{
    name: 'Person 1',
    age: '30'
  },
  {
    name: 'Person 2',
    age: '28'
  },
];

const info = document.querySelector('#info');

let details = data.map(function(item) {
  return '<div>' + item.name + ' ' + 'is ' + item.age + "</div>";
});

info.innerHTML = details.join("\n");
```

```css
#info div {
  border: 1px dotted #07f;
  margin: 0.3em;
  padding: 1.2em;
  border-radius: 0.6em;
}
```

```html
<div id="info"></div>
```

#### ES6 syntax

Now, it can be made a little cleanly if you use the ES6 syntax, like the following:

```js
let data = [{
    name: 'Person 1',
    age: '30'
  },
  {
    name: 'Person 2',
    age: '28'
  },
];

const info = document.querySelector('#info');

let details = data.map(item => `<div>${item.name} is ${item.age}</div>`);

info.innerHTML = details.join("\n");
```

```css
#info div {
  border: 1px dotted #07f;
  margin: 0.3em;
  padding: 1.2em;
  border-radius: 0.6em;
}
```

```html
<div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: the issue with that is that it adds a comma after each object. How do I get rid of the comma that shows as it maps through the data?

Comment: oops, my bad... it was an array, and we could use `join()` to join them. Now fixed.

Comment: what exactly does the "\n" do? I don't get why that removes the comma

Comment: You can take a look at my answer @Johnxr

Comment: @Johnxr  `\n` is commonly for the newline (or really the linefeed) character...  you could also just use `join("")` without joining them using a character. The `\n` just makes it better formatted with the newline

Comment: Why there was a comma: because it was an array, with two elements, so JS dumped them out as a string with a comma separating the elements.  The proper way, often, to join an array of strings, is using `join()`

Comment: is it not possible to replicate JSX methods with regular html and js? Example like in the html i'd just pass <div>{item.name}</div> and <p>{item.age}</p> so it just updates dynamically? I don't think it's possible unless you're using react, but I just wanted to make sure

Comment: AFAIK, people can use JSX without using React, but you have to include the JSX module to make it work. If it is simple HTML, then it might be an overkill... it depends on your usage

Comment: but note, when you have JSX, those are DOM elements, and is a bit more complicated to deal with. If you have simple markup, you may as well just use HTML and `innerHTML`

Comment: @Johnxr thanks very much, having me spent 20 minute on your problem and you giving me 0 point at all